# How to create SKPhysicsBody with holes?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I was wondering how I could create a more complex SKPhysicsyBody like this? I want to hittest againt the black parts.

[image]

I exported this shape with PaintCode to a CG Rect.

```
var barrierpath2Path = UIBezierPath()
        barrierpath2Path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(52, 26))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(52, 26))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(26, 52), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(52, 40.36), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(40.36, 52))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(26, 52))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 26), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(11.64, 52), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(0, 40.36))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 26))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(26, 0), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(0, 11.64), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(11.64, 0))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(26, 0))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(52, 26), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(40.36, 0), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(52, 11.64))
        barrierpath2Path.closePath()
        barrierpath2Path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(46.8, 26))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(46.8, 26))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(39, 18.2), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(46.8, 21.69), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(43.31, 18.2))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(39, 18.2))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(31.2, 26), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(34.69, 18.2), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(31.2, 21.69))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(31.2, 26))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(39, 33.8), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(31.2, 30.31), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(34.69, 33.8))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(39, 33.8))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(46.8, 26), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(43.31, 33.8), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(46.8, 30.31))
        barrierpath2Path.closePath()
        barrierpath2Path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(27.3, 14.74))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(27.3, 14.74))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(19.5, 6.94), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(27.3, 10.43), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(23.81, 6.94))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(19.5, 6.94))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(11.7, 14.74), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(15.19, 6.94), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(11.7, 10.43))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(11.7, 14.74))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(19.5, 22.54), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(11.7, 19.05), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(15.19, 22.54))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(19.5, 22.54))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(27.3, 14.74), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(23.81, 22.54), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(27.3, 19.05))
        barrierpath2Path.closePath()
        barrierpath2Path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(27.3, 37.26))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(27.3, 37.26))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(19.5, 29.46), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(27.3, 32.95), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(23.81, 29.46))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(19.5, 29.46))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(11.7, 37.26), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(15.19, 29.46), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(11.7, 32.95))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(11.7, 37.26))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(19.5, 45.06), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(11.7, 41.57), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(15.19, 45.06))
        barrierpath2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(19.5, 45.06))
        barrierpath2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(27.3, 37.26), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(23.81, 45.06), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(27.3, 41.57))
        barrierpath2Path.closePath()
        barrierpath2Path.miterLimit = 4;



        monster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: barrierpath2Path.CGPath)
```

But the simulator shows just one hole (and the png behind)? What's wrong here?
[image]

Comment: So just a heads up, in game programming you don't typically draw one physics body for the above in one shot (that's not how physics body's are designed to be used, physics bodies are meant to be simple shapes.. like triangles, squares, circles). Especially with SKPhysicsBody (which has issues with concave versus convex drawings). You're going to what to divi up the physics bodies into separate parts and form the above body as closely as you can. Think of it as polygons on a render.

Comment: Thanks. I need that shape as it is. But I have no idea how to rebuild that shape from smaller physics bodies. Maybe I should look for something else than PhysicsBody. e.g. CGPathContainsPoint()

Comment: It depends whether you want to: a) be able to move the whole shape b) have bodies collide with both outside of the shape and other bodies within the holes. If you don't need to move it, you can set up edge chain/loop forming the outlines.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely want to make the holes child nodes with their own physics bodies. This will allow everything to have their own respective physics bodies and move in accordance to each other without any problems

To further elaborate on this answer, you might also be able to use the SKPhysicsBody convenience initializer to create a physics body off of the alpha values in a texture. This will incur a performance hit, but should do what you want it to.

```
l.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: l.texture, size: l.size)
```

Comment: not sure why this is not the accepted answer. this is most likely the easier way to achieve what is being asked! :)

Comment: Sadly `SKPhysicsBody(texture:size:)` does not handle non-contiguous shapes. Given the sprite shown in the question, it will just generate the outer circle.